# GRASS GIS code - equations used in the modules

Tags: grass-gis

How can I view the equations used in the GRASS GIS modules?
I found the code here:
1) URL: https://trac.osgeo.org/…/re…/raster/r.watershed/front/main.c;
2) URL: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/tree/master/raster/r.watershed?fbclid=IwAR24KBPYl8iQjGQMphtl54dri5T0hU8cU5Q9DYycgAjeFG7RYQ8SVvAMn0Q
But not the expressions.

Comment: Dig deeper? See https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/raster/r.watershed/seg/sg_factor.c#L65 What exact equation are you looking for?

Comment: Hint: Out https://grassbook.org/ comes with an appendix, explaining in-depth numerous equations implemented in GRASS GIS.

Comment: @mankoff, for LS equations. a) NETELER & MITASOVA (2008, pp. 158-166, 382), display LS equation in SI units; b) RENARD et al. (1997, p. 104) display LS equation not SI units; c) MITASOVA et al. (1996), display LS equation in SI units. d) github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/raster/r.watershed/seg/…, display LS equation not in SI units? I see some terms "feet". Note that d)(code) is different from expressions in a). Was expecting form something like: lsfac=1.6*exp(flowacc*resolution/22.1,0.6)*exp(sin(slope)/0.09,1.3). Any comments? The LS GRASS code uses SI units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning to the code (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/raster/r.watershed/seg/sg_factor.c#L68), the GUI gets the MDE in SI units and converts them to USA feet units:

```
int sg_factor(void)
{
    int r, c;
    CELL low_elev, hih_elev;
    double height, length, S, sin_theta;
    WAT_ALT wa;
    ASP_FLAG af;

    G_message(_("SECTION 5: RUSLE LS and/or S factor determination."));
    for (r = nrows - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
    G_percent(nrows - r, nrows, 3);
    for (c = ncols - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
        seg_get(&aspflag, (char *)&af, r, c);
        if (FLAG_GET(af.flag, NULLFLAG))
        continue;

        seg_get(&watalt, (char *)&wa, r, c);
        low_elev = wa.ele;
        cseg_get(&r_h, &hih_elev, r, c);
        dseg_get(&s_l, &length, r, c);
        height = 1.0 * (hih_elev - low_elev) / ele_scale;
        if (length > max_length) {
        height *= max_length / length;
        length = max_length;
        }
        sin_theta = height / sqrt(height * height + length * length);
        if (height / length < .09)
        S = 10.8 * sin_theta + .03;
        else
        S = 16.8 * sin_theta - .50;
        if (ls_flag) {
        length *= METER_TO_FOOT;
        len_slp_equ(length, sin_theta, S, r, c);
        }
        if (sg_flag) {
        dseg_put(&s_g, &S, r, c);
        }
    }
    }
    G_percent(nrows, nrows, 1);    /* finish it */

    return 0;
}

int len_slp_equ(double slope_length, double sin_theta, double S, int r, int c)
{
    double rill, s_l_exp,    /* m                            */
      rill_ratio,        /* Beta                         */
      LS;

    rill_ratio = (sin_theta / 0.0896) / (3.0 * pow(sin_theta, 0.8) + 0.56);
    if (ril_flag) {
    dseg_get(&ril, &rill, r, c);
    }
    else if (ril_value >= 0.0) {
    rill = ril_value;
    }
    else
    rill = 0.0;
    /* rill_ratio equation from Steve Warren */
    rill_ratio *= .5 + .005 * rill + .0001 * rill * rill;
    s_l_exp = rill_ratio / (1 + rill_ratio);
    LS = S * pow((slope_length / 72.6), s_l_exp);
       dseg_put(&l_s, &LS, r, c);

        return 0;
}
```